# Storing a date in core data

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm able to get today's date using the following in Objective-c:

```
NSDate *date =[NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterLongStyle; 
[ASFunctions logThis:@"formatted date:" andThisObject:[df stringFromDate:date]];
```

However, I also want to insert this into a SQLite database using the Core Data framework.

I have been able to insert user entered text using the following:

```
Project.name = text.nameTextField.self;
```

Where project.name is the entity name and attribute. I am using project.dateStarted to store the date.

After grabbing the date using the functions above, how would I store it into the project.dateStarted attribute of the core database?

Comment: is `dateStarted` field of Date type (in your xdatamodel)? If so, you use `Project.dateStarted = date;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If dateStarted is defined as a date attribute in the model, just assign the NSDate to it and save the context.

```
project.dateStarted = date;
```

will do the trick.

Comment: Ok, it is set as a date attribute, but my question should have said, Syntactically, how do I do this? I'm struggling to understand how to assign the NSDate variable to project.dateStarted, even if it's a very simple thing to do.

Comment: I knew I was overcomplicating it. Thanks Jeremy