# How to save date type to an attribute of an entity in Core Data in Swift?

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, nsdate

I want to set current date to my entity at the time when it is initialized by an user, so I tried to use `NSDate` and set its instance to the attribute in Swift, like:

```
task.date = NSDate() // task is an instance of Entity class
```

However, this code returns an error: `NSDate is not a subtype of NSNumber`. Actually this code worked in Objective-C, which is used in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412365/storing-a-date-in-core-data).

Note that I properly set the attribute's type to `date` in my `xcdatamodeld` file. Also, the other attribute (like `title`, which is just a `string` type) is successfully assigned the data to. So how can I use `date` to my Core Data object in Swift app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that you have defined the `NSManagedObject` subclass correctly:

```
@objc(Task)
class Task: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var date: NSDate
}
```

Tested. First line is optional for this scenario.

Comment: Thanks. I found that the error arose because I checked on the `use scalar properties for primitive data types` when instantiating the managed object class and it converted `NSDate` to `NSTimeInterval` automatically.